# How to disable lock screen in Windows 10 Home Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10

I managed to disable the lock screen in Windows 10 Home before the Anniversary update. After the update, I found ways to disable it but they require me to have Windows 10 Pro.

Any solution for Windows 10 Home?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/05/disable-windows-10-lock-screen/

Comment: It can't be disabled, not really, I any event the group policy editor can be placed on Windows 10 Home easily enough

Comment: Thanks for the other thread. For some reason, it didn't show up in my Google searches. The patcher method worked for me. The others failed or half-worked. Actually, I combined all 3 solutions (renamed the "lock" app folder, applied the patch, have the scheduled task too!). "Kill it until it's dead" kind of :D. I'm sure Microsoft will be kind enough to mess with this solution too, but I'll stay away from their updates for a while.